# How to know if the next row had the same value with a condition using dask?

Tags: python, dask

I had this dataframe:

```
timestamp,user_id,action,adId,campaignId 
2016-09-21 22:11:00,7c74953c-66cc-48bd-9d02-a02bf039cf3f,click,adId_09,campaignId_01  
2016-06-25 18:29:00,676a083e-2f8e-4ff2-9ec2-270f7f9d6033,view,adId_09,campaignId_02  
2016-02-14 19:03:00,77158997-0dfa-48b7-9149-973dc151ef8d,click,adId_02,campaignId_02  
2016-03-26 06:27:00,78aa2467-b502-413b-94e9-04ec8210bd13,click,adId_07,campaignId_03
```

I need to know if my user view and click (sequentitly) the same campaign and anouncement

Comment: I just reformatted your data - check out the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) to see how this can be done. However, your question still isn't very clear to me. Can you please show us exactly what you are expecting as an output, and provide code showing what you've tried and what's not working? Can you write out the code in a way that works in pandas that we could help you apply to dask? Thanks!

Comment: 2016-07-09 21:42:00 be3befb9-ee08-4311-89f4-430d23ee63f1 view  adId_09 campaignId_01
2016-07-18 21:15:00 be3befb9-ee08-4311-89f4-430d23ee63f1 click  adId_09 campaignId_01

Comment: I am not familiar with dask python library. Meanwhile, I think you should use regular `if/else, list[1][action] == list[action]` something like this conditions to check whether the next row has the same value.

Comment: @TulaMagar sorry but if you're not familiar with dask, you don't have to comment. this is very bad advice for the posed question. dask.dataframe is very much not a list.

Comment: In situations where there is a view event followed by a click event created by the same user in the same ad and campaign, I need to get the 5 ad and campaign pairs with the lowest average time between the two events

Comment: @CaioSerpa can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74185138/edit) the question to clarify your intent rather than commenting? and no need to indicate that it's an edit - the changes will be tracked in the [revisions log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74185138/revisions) - just edit the question to make it as clear as possible - thanks!

Comment: also - @CaioSerpa - the task of checking whether the user and campaign have changed from one row to another is I think doable with [`dask.dataframe.rolling.map_overlap`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.rolling.map_overlap.html), but the goal of finding the 5 ad and campaign pairs with the lowest average time between events is a radically different question which I think will be pretty tough to pull off with dask.dataframe, assuming you have a very large number of users*campaign combos? this seems better suited for a database query.